# Is this a good case for the Strategy Pattern

Tags: csv, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have the following inputs:

1. A CSV File
2. An array of grammar rules.  The grammar rules are
       basically metadata that tells me what which each column datatype
       should be.

The output would return back to me a list of records that had any errors. So if column should be a date but I'm given the wrong format.  I would return those rows.

The csv file would be something like this:

```
first_name,last_name,dob,age,
john,doe,2001/05/02
mary,jane,1968/04/01
```

Metadata:

```
column:first_name
type:string

column:dob
type:date
```

I was wondering if the strategy pattern would be the right choice. I was thinking of injecting the proper grammar (metadata) depending upon the file.  I have multiple files I want to validate.

Comment: What you are referring to is probably plain old composition rather than the *Strategy* pattern.

Comment: @MindGame - Strategy pattern talks about interchangeable family of algorithms, which are applied (attached) to context only one at a time. In present problem statement, if rules are imagined to be algorithms, they are applied simultaneously to different columns and not interchangeable. If a rule for same column changes in between without change in state, then that portion can be implemented as Strategy otherwise not an appropriate candidate for Strategy.

Comment: @KedarTokekar Thank you for the explanation.  You make a good point.  What design pattern would be good in this case then?

Comment: @MindGame - Chain of Responsibility (aka COR) comes to my mind. but before we apply, I need to know whether your column names are dynamically available after reading first row of csv or known a priory (as a fixed set). Another assumption is column type rules are in terms of set of primitive data types. meaning no rule will be applied to more than one column. (e.g. rule will not say column 1+ 2 + 3 will form full name, instead it will say col1- fName and so on)

Comment: @KedarTokekar  The columns for the file can come in any order.  Meaning if I had a csv file which gives me first name, last name and dob.  It could come in any order.  Only one rule will be applied to each column. Not sure if I answered all your questions.

Comment: @MindGame - provided detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem needs the Validation Handlers (for your grammar rule). Looking at lower complexity level and expected extensions, I do not feel the need of any specific design pattern. I would suggest following simple OO approach. Alternatively depending upon expected dynamic behavior, COR can be incorporated by putting each Concrete Handler in a chain (COR). Pass each token in a chain so as to give opportunity to handlers in a chain till it gets handled.

```
public class Extractor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // PREPARE TEMP_MAP_HANDLERS<Type,Handler>
        Map<String, Handler> handlers = new HashMap<>();
        handlers.put("FIRST_NAME",new NAMEHandler());
        handlers.put("LAST_NAME",new NAMEHandler());
        handlers.put("DOB",new DOBHandler());
        handlers.put("AGE",new AGEHandler());
        // READ THE HEADER
        String header = "first_name,last_name,dob,age";// SAMPLE READ HEADER
        // PREPARE LOOKUP<COL_INDEX, TYPE_HANDLER> 
        Map<Integer, Handler> metaHandlers = new HashMap<>();
        String[] headerTokens = header.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < headerTokens.length; i++) {
            metaHandlers.put(i, handlers.get(headerTokens[i].toUpperCase()));
        }
        // DONE WITH TEMP HANDLER LOOKUP 
        // READ ACTUAL ROWS
        // FOR EACH ROW IN FILE
        String row = "joh*n,doe,2001/05/02";
        String[] rowTokens = row.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < rowTokens.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(rowTokens[i]);
            Handler handler = metaHandlers.get(i);
            if (!handler.validate(rowTokens[i])){
                // REPORT WRONG DATA
                System.out.println("Wrong Token" + rowTokens[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
abstract class Handler {
    abstract boolean validate (String field);
}

class NAMEHandler extends Handler{
    @Override
    boolean validate(String field) {
        // Arbitrary rule - name should not contain *
        return !field.contains("*");
    }
}

class DOBHandler extends Handler{
    @Override
    boolean validate(String field) {
        // Arbitrary rule - contains /
        return field.contains("/");
    }
}

class AGEHandler extends Handler{
    @Override
    boolean validate(String field) {
        // TODO validate AGE
        return true;
    }
}
```